# Web API controller re-instantiate a singleton service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am working on a Web API in ASP.Net Core using dependency injection.
There is multiple singletons services which are launched during startup.
When I try to access these services via an API they are reinstatiated (althought they are singletons). So I come again inside the constructor of my Singleton Service, instead of using the Singleton already instatiated during the startup.

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddSingleton<IMySingleton, MySingleton>();
```

*MyAPIController.cs*

```
private readonly IMySingleton _mySingleton;

public MyController( IMySingleton mySingleton )
{
    this._mySingleton = mySingleton;
}

[Route("[action]")]
[HttpGet]
public bool MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        _mySingleton.MethodOfSingleton();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I access my existing singleton from my WebAPI instead of create a new singleton?

Comment: Using singleton pattern ? private constructor and instantiate static method maybee ?   [example](https://codeburst.io/singleton-design-pattern-implementation-in-c-62a8daf3d115) but i don't understand how singleton be instantiate again , give just one instance that's precisely the purpose of the pattern

Comment: DI takes care of details and gives you the same instance of `IMySingleton` whenever u inject it (because you define its lifetime in the `Startup`). How do you know it creates a new singleton?

Comment: About "which are launched during startup": are you only registering it with this line of code or doing some other logic that makes use of an instance of your singleton class? (In which case you should instantiate it and then register the already created instance in DI, but I can only guess what your whole code looks like)

Comment: @MartinUllrich it's launched elsewhere indeed

Comment: @Progressive I know it because I put a breakpoint in the constructor of MySingleton

Comment: @valerianHavaux I use static method as a work around, but I don't think it's a good thing

Comment: @Nicolas.S That breakpoint actually may give you a hint. Can you check the call stack when the debugger hit the breakpoint?

Comment: Thanks, good advice, actually he calls it at the beginning, and then just one time when I call it with the controller. When I call again the controller we don't go again into the constructor...

Comment: Do you use the official .NET Core DI or a 3rd Party DI implementation? 
Also did you try warm-up the DI by getting a instance of `IMySingleton` inside your `Startup.Configure` to prevent threading issues? (e.g. many parallel connections during startup, also `Startup.Configure` is still single-threaded before the server listens)

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution, instead of inject directly the singleton in the Controller constructor, you should pass the services inside:

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddSingleton<IMySingleton, MySingleton>();
```

*MyAPIController.cs*

```
private readonly MySingleton mysingleton

public MyAPIController(IEnumerable<IHostedService> services)
{
    this.mysingleton = services.FirstOrDefault(hs => hs.GetType() == typeof(MySingleton )) as MySingleton ;
}
```

In this way, the singleton MySingleton is not reinstantiate each time the Controller is called.